# JLabel doesn't change back color

Tags: java, swing, background, boolean, jlabel

Part of my function looks like this

```
jLabel2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
jLabel2.setText("Status : Idle");

boolean ok=cpu21.RestartSSH();

if(ok){
    jLabel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jLabel2.setText("Status : Run");    
}
```

Before I enter in function label is Green and Run, but when I come in function it doesn't chabge color to Yellow ( function RestartSSH is executing 5-6 sec, but during that time labels doesn't change colors and captures ). Where I make mistake in painting ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Make your JLabel opaque so you can set its background colour.
- Perform `RestartSSH` in a separate thread, or your GUI won't respond to events.

Example:

```
final JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel("HELLO");
jLabel2.setOpaque(true);
jLabel2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
jLabel2.setText("Status : Idle");

//perform SSH in a separate thread
Thread sshThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        boolean ok=cpu21.RestartSSH();
        if(ok){
           //update the GUI in the event dispatch thread
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   jLabel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                   jLabel2.setText("Status : Run");
               }
           });
        }
    }
};
sshThread.start();
```

(Update: added call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`)

Comment: Add SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..) for the UI calls on the spawned thread and you're golden

Comment: +1 This is the right idea, but the `Thread` should use `invokeLater()`, as suggested here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style#Continuations_as_objects

Answer (score 5):

JLabels is opaque by default, so their's background isn't painted by default. Try with:

```
jLabel2.setOpaque(true);
```

or maybe you have to call repaint after changing the color:

```
jLabel2.repaint();
```

Comment: Because *JLabel's background is transparent by default* +1

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your `restartSSH()` method is blocking the [*event dispatch thread*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). One approach is to use a `SwingWorker`, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725). This would allow you to show the progress of the restart process and set the label appropriately when done.